# Homebrew mysql config

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, my.cnf

I had install mysql by this guide

http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/

and copy my.cnf file to /etc dir, but mysql not started :(

mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/folivora.dlink.pid).

without /etc/my.cnf — mysql started successful :(

any ideas?

Comment: I think you actually want to copy it it `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: yes, i had copied from this dir, but not luck :(

Comment: can someone give an worked copy of my.cnf ?